# Residuals and plots in ordered multinomial regression

Tags: r, plot, regression, ordinal

I need to plot a binned residual plot with fitted versus residual values from an ordered multinominal logit regression.

How can I extract residuals when using polr? Is there any other function that runs ord multinominal logit in which residuals can be extracted?

This is the code I used

```
options(contrasts = c("contr.treatment", "contr.poly"))
mod1 <- polr(as.ordered(y) ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data, method='logistic')

fit <- mod1$fitted.values
res <- residuals(mod1)
binnedplot(fit, res)
```

The problem is that object 'res' is 'null'.

Thanks

Comment: Can I take a look at the data? (I won't be able to answer because i don't know R so well, but i would like to replicate to learn) thanks

Comment: @moldovean, the `MASS` package help page for the `polr` function does have some example data sets.

Comment: Gelman & Hill present a way to calculate residuals for ordinal logistic regressions. They calculate a weighted average for each case based on cut points, calculate residuals, and then bin these residuals for graphical presentation.

Answer (score 2):

For a start, can you tell us how residuals would be defined **in principle** for a model with categorical responses? `fitted.values` is a matrix of probabilities.  You could define residuals in terms of correct prediction (defining the most likely outcome as the prediction, as in the default `predict` method for `polr` objects) -- or you could compute an n-by-n table of true values and predicted values. Alternatively you could reduce the ordinal data back to an integer scale and compute a mean outcome as the prediction ... but I can't see that there's any unique way to define the residuals in the first place.

Comment: I know this is a really old answer, but I saw that you are still active on stack.. so I thought I'd give it a try. I would like to use a control function (CF) / two stage residual inclusion (2SRI) with a `polr` in the first stage. I was wondering if any of your different suggestions on how to calculate the residuals from the `polr` would be suitable for this purpose (the 2SLS approach would be to include the fitted values of `polr`, but the result would inconsistent when mimicking the 2SLS, and I don't know any software that does an ordinal-2SLS directly).

Comment: I posted a question about my comment on CrossValidated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/518535/how-to-get-residuals-from-an-ordinal-logit-probit-and-which-ones-to-get

Answer (score 0):

In polr(), there is no function that returns residual. You should manually calculate it using its definition.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually plenty of ways to get residuals from an ordinal probit/logit. Although `polr` does not provide any residuals, `vglm` provides several. See `?residualsvglm` from the `VGAM`package (see also below).

**NOTE: However, for a Control Function/2SRI approach Wooldridge (2014) suggests using the generalised residuals as described in Vella (1993). These are as far as I know currently not available in `R`, although [I am working on that](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/521808/generalised-residuals-estimated-value-of-the-density-at-that-point-for-observa), but they are in Stata (using `predict gr, score`)**

## Residuals in VLGM

[image]

## Surrogate residuals for polr

You can use the package `sure` ([link](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2018/RJ-2018-004/RJ-2018-004.pdf#section.2.2)), to calculate surrogate residuals with `resids`. The package is based on [this paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/01621459.2017.1292915), in the Journal of the American Statistical Association.

```
library(sure) # for residual function and sample data sets
library(MASS) # for polr function

df1 <- df1
df1$x1 <- df1$x
df1$x <- NULL
df1$y <- df2$y
df1$x2 <- df2$x
df1$x3 <- df3$x

options(contrasts = c("contr.treatment", "contr.poly"))
mod1 <- polr(as.ordered(y) ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data=df1, method='probit')

fit <- mod1$fitted.values
res <- resids(mod1)
```

EDIT: One big issue is the following (from `?resids`):

*"Note: Surrogate residuals require sampling from a continuous distribution; consequently, the result will be different with every call to resids. The internal functions used for sampling from truncated distributions when method = "latent" are based on modified versions of rtrunc and qtrunc."*

Even when running `resids(mod1, nsim=1000, method="latent")`, there is no convergence of the outcome.